# Are there any libraries that support Android images to add watermarks?

Tags: android, bitmap

I tried for a long time and couldn't get any better,On different mobile phones:
1. I would like to add pictures and words to the sourceBitmap.
2. want to be able to adjust bitmap and word positions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using library simply we can watermark image using canvas and paint concept

```
 Point point=new Point();
 point.set(180, 1000);
 Bitmap b=waterMark(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image),"your Text",point,Color.WHITE,90,30,true);
 imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

the method code

```
public  Bitmap waterMark(Bitmap src, String watermark, Point location, int color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
 //get source image width and height
 int w = src.getWidth();
 int h = src.getHeight();

 Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
 //create canvas object
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
 //draw bitmap on canvas
 canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
 //create paint object
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 //apply color
 paint.setColor(color);
 //set transparency
 paint.setAlpha(alpha);
 //set text size
 paint.setTextSize(size);
 paint.setAntiAlias(true);
 //set should be underlined or not
 paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
 //draw text on given location
  canvas.drawText(watermark, location.x, location.y, paint); 
 return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but it is difficult to customize. I try to back through the waterMaker.xml ->bitmap, but the calculation of the size of the watermark in the different size of the bitmap, and the final show in imageView, the effect is not very good

Comment: you can customize alpha values for transparency of water mark text

Answer (score 1):

This method will automatically adjust the size of the watermark text according to the size of bitmap. Additionally it will also add the watermark diagonally if the image is portrait and horizontal if image is landscape

```
public static Bitmap waterMark(Bitmap src, String watermark, int color, int alpha, int size) {
    //get source image width and height
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();


    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());
    //create canvas object
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    //draw bitmap on canvas
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
    //create paint object
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    //apply color
    paint.setColor(color);

    //set transparency
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    //set text size
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    Paint stkPaint = new Paint();
    stkPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    stkPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    stkPaint.setTextSize(size);
    stkPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    stkPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    stkPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    //set should be underlined or not

    //draw text on given location
    canvas.save();

    float width = paint.measureText(watermark);
    Logger.e("width of bitmap", "" + w);
    Logger.e("width of text", "" + width);
    if (width > w) {
        int i = 2;
        while (width > w) {
            paint.setTextSize(size - i);
            stkPaint.setTextSize(size - i);
            width = paint.measureText(watermark);
            Logger.e("width of text", "" + width);
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        int i = 2;
        while (width < w) {
            paint.setTextSize(size + i);
            stkPaint.setTextSize(size + i);
            width = paint.measureText(watermark);
            Logger.e("width of text", "" + width);
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (w < h) {
        canvas.rotate(-60, src.getWidth() / 2, src.getHeight() / 2);
    }


    float final_x = (src.getWidth() - width) / 2;
    Point p = new Point();
    p.set((int) final_x, src.getHeight() / 2);

    canvas.drawText(watermark, p.x, p.y, paint);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, p.x, p.y, stkPaint);

    canvas.restore();

    return result;
}
```